# Is there a way to translate this 'while' loop into a 'for' loop in python?

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I have a decimal-to-any base converter as shown below:

```
import string
digs = string.digits + string.ascii_letters

def int2base(x, base):
    if x < 0:
        sign = -1
    elif x == 0:
        return digs[0]
    else:
        sign = 1

    x *= sign
    digits = []
    
    while x:
        digits.append(digs[x % base])
        x = x // base
    if sign < 0:
        digits.append('-')
    digits.reverse()
    return ''.join(digits)

print(int2base(51363,64))
```

... And I want to replace the `while` loop here with a `for` loop but I've tried and failed to do so.
Help is apreciated (•‿•)

Comment: Why? A while-loop is the right one for that.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this?  Is the `while` loop not doing something you need?  Would a `for` loop be faster?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? A while loop is exactly right for this: As long as x is not zero, you keep calculating digits and reducing x by means of division, up to the point when it does reach zero. I suppose you could use a for loop to loop through the individual digits in x and do arithmetic on them, but that’d be a less elegant solution than what is currently there.

Comment: I agree. `while` loop is the natural way of thinking about this. However, it is possible to convert this to a `for` loop. Hint: Each digit is a different power of the base.

Comment: @MYousefi How are you going to generate the sequence of powers to iterate over, though? Fundamentally, this requires *generating* a sequence, not iterating over one. (In functional programming terms, it's an unfold, not a fold.)

Comment: My sole purpose is to translate this function into a lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly answer to a silly question :-)

Instead of

```
while x:
```

you could do:

```
for _ in iter(lambda: x, 0):
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer Pychopath:

```
i2b = lambda x,base,res=0:[[(x<0and[sign:=-1])or(x>0and[sign:=1])or(x==0and[res:=digs[0]])]and res][0]or[x:=x*sign,digits:=[]]and([[digits.append(digs[x%base]),x:=x//base]for _ in iter(lambda:x,0)])and[digits.append('-') if sign<0 else 0]and(res:=''.join(digits[::-1]))
```